# Why is ISql100DatabaseEncryptionKey blocking Schema Compare

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, database-schema

I am trying to do a Schema Compare in Visual Studio 2010 on some SQL Server 2008 databases. But I get the following error. What does it mean and how can I ignore?

```
An error was received from SQL Server while attempting to reverse engineer elements of type Microsoft.Data.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.ISql100DatabaseEncryptionKey: The user does not have permission to perform this action.
```

Update: "Write Updates" does actually work. But I can't "Export to editor".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. The only fix I found so far is to run the comparison as a user with the sysadmin Server Role. Even selecting to ignore Database Encryption Keys gives this error which seems broken to me. I filed a bug on connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552986/schema-compare-permission-error-for-database-encryption-keys-even-though-the-type-is-set-to-be-ignored

Comment: Thank you for reporting this to Microsoft. It is troublesome when like me is having the database on a web host where I can not change the user roles.

Comment: Microsoft closed it as won't fix, however they did give some details on specific permissions that need to be granted to avoid this error (I haven't had a chance to try it yet) - check out the connect link above for details.  

I think they should have made it workable with a default setup and a login that has db_owner to the database you are working with but I guess they disagree.

Comment: The user I'm connecting with has the sysadmin server role, and it's still producing the error.

Comment: @MegaMatt Steve Campbell notes that VS 2010 SP1 resolves the issue. Give that a try if you haven't already.

Comment: I'm still encountering the issue on VS 2010 SP1, and the Connect link now appears to be broken. Here's the archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20110819201500/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/552986/schema-compare-permission-error-for-database-encryption-keys-even-though-the-type-is-set-to-be-ignored

Answer (score 2):

I found a work around that works for me.

http://www.richardmaxwell.name/blog/2011/3/2/work-around-isql100databaseencryptionkey-blocking-schema-com.html

Answer (score 2):

VS2010 sp1 fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Sure does! The Error is a Warning now, permitting you to continue your work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned "Write Updates" works and after you update target database you will be able to generate script using "Export To Editor".